# The return of a function repeats the same record

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

From frontend I will send this JSON to backend:

```
{
    "tech": ["html"],
    "city": "zurich"
}
```

This is how I get the data dynamically from my database:

```
public function user($uid, $selection, $tables) {
    // 1. Query builder
    $queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')->select($selection)->where('u.uid = :uid');

    // 2. Get each table
    foreach ($tables as $key => $value) {
        $queryBuilder = $queryBuilder->innerJoin('App\Entity\\' . $value, $key)->andWhere("$key.uid = :uid");
    }

    // 3. Finish and return the query
    return $queryBuilder
        ->setParameter('uid', $uid)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult()
    ;
}
```

If I turn the return of this method into JSON, this will be the result:

```
{
    "88": {
        "data": [
            {
                "tech": "PHP",
                "city": "Zurich"
            },
            {
                "tech": "JavaScript",
                "city": "Zurich"
            },
            {
                "tech": "HTML",
                "city": "Zurich"
            }
        ],
        "rank": 200
    },
    "33": {
        "data": [
            {
                "tech": "HTML",
                "city": "zurich"
            }
        ],
        "rank": 200
    }
}
```

So we have information about 2 users (`88` and `33`). The array `data` from the ID `33` looks good and that's how it supposed to be. But the array `data` from the ID `88` looks messed up. This is how it should look like:

```
  "data": [
            {
                "tech": ["PHP", "JavaScript", "HTML"],
                "city": "Zurich"
            }
        ]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: read up on aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

you should use an aggregate function group by city like this:

```html
select group_concat(tech), city from tbl1
group by city
```

Comment: I have tried this but then my data array looks like this: `"data": [ { "tech": "PHP", "city": "Zurich" } ]`. As you see `tech` includes a string but it should contain an array.

Comment: i will build this data in a table and will try to show you the right sql :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But how can I do this with Symfony? I have tried it with `$queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')->select($selection)->where('u.uid = :uid')->addSelect('GROUP_CONCAT(tech)')->groupBy('u.city');` but it gives me an error.